# Multi-light dimmer switch broken: one light dims, other lights brighten

Tags: lighting, switch, dimmer-switch

I have 3 light installations in my kitchen that are controlled by one of two switches. The switches either turn all 3 lights on/off, or dims/brightens all 3 lights at the same time (with a long press).

Lights cannot be turned off individually, or dimmed individually, only from these two switches.

However! Today, something changed: when dimming the lights, 2 of the lights dim (correctly), but the other light brightens. When brightening the lights, only 2 brighten, but the other dims: the relationship appears to be inverted.

This change happened spontaneously: I didn't do any re-wiring, change any bulbs, etc.

This behaviour is exhibited when using either of the two switches.

The below picture is of the dimmer: the top switch is the problematic one. The bottom switch controls a different light, which is working properly.

How should I try and debug this issue?

[image: Picture of the faulty light switch]

Comment: Call Ghostbusters ... sorry. Can you switch the two dimmer switches and see if the problem still remains or moves with the switch.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like the dimmer is supplying power to two of the lamps, and wired ACROSS the other lamp. But, you didn't make any changes, so go figure. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.